# 3D Studio Max 9 - Not opening (freezes at the welcome screen)

Tags: windows-10, directx, 3dsmax

I have a legit license of 3D Studio Max 9, I tried to install it in Windows 10.
Now, when launching it, it freezes at the welcome screen, and doesn't display some UI elements.
I already had this issue before, and I solved it by installing DirectX 9, but now they're installed and the problem came back.
Should I reinstall DX9? If so, how to remove them before?
And if not, what could I do?

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm attaching a screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQAZu.png)

P.S.: I forgot to mention, I can't move any 3dsm window, and I can stop it from task manager only.

Comment: Please, help me some way

Comment: After updating Windows to 21H1, the problem got fixed.